# Is it good to use dependency injection in a java library?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I have a play application and want to take a common operation out from the application and make it as a library in order to use in other play applications.

This proposing library has a contract(interface) and several implementations of top of that.

What if I use guice to bind contact and implementations with named injection(using annotations) and call them with the appropriate annotation in the play application without instantiating library classes in the apply application?

Comment: This question is a request for opinions, and such questions aren't allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ will be a better place to ask this question

Comment: i would say that IT depends on the context... how big is the project for start? are you expecting to work with different interfaces at different levels of abstractions?

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to know is there any best practice for this. Anyway, I'll move this to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Victor, my concern is such libraries(wrapped with DI) can use in an application that doesn't use Guice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine to use DI in a library, although that would add a restriction that the library users will be forced to use DI as well. I usually use DI in the java libraries that I write but then I wrap the client-facing interfaces with factories. That way, you get best of both worlds!

Comment: Thanks, Have you any experience of using such libraries in other frameworks? Ex: A library used Guice DI, can we use in a java application that doesn't use Guice(May be Spring)